# Property binding inside of property binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a an array of objects:

```
collections = [
          {name: 'one', productOne: 'image-url', productTwo: 'image-url'},
          {name: 'two', productOne: 'image-url', productTwo: 'image-url'},
          {name: 'three', productOne: 'image-url', productTwo: 'image-url'},
          {name: 'four', productOne: 'image-url', productTwo: 'image-url'},
]
```

As you can see, each object contains an image url. Let's say I'm on productTwo's product page, hence I want to display productTwo's image. I additionally have an object (`product`), that contains the product's name, hence I know the product's name of the product page I'm on.

How do I display the correct image? You can find the issue's location by the three question marks.

I can't just use `collection.productTwo`, since the product page is supposed to be dynamic and should be adjusted to the current product's page.

This might sound confusing, but this approach might illustrate it a little more:

```
<img [src]="collection. + product.name" [alt]="collection.name" class="w-75 align-self-center">
```

Is this even possible?

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0 top-container" *ngIf="product" [style.position]="fixed && !collections ? 'fixed' : 'static'">

  <div class="container-fluid bg-test justify-content-center min-vh-100 d-flex">
    <h1 class="align-self-center">{{product.name}}</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center d-flex collections" *ngIf="collections" [style.position]="fixed && collections ? 'fixed' : 'static'">
    <div class="row align-self-center justify-content-around">
      <div class="col-12 mb-5 text-center">
        <h1>ALL COLLECTIONS</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let collection of collections">
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h4>{{collection.name}}</h4>
            <p>- {{collection.desc}} -</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img [src]="???" [alt]="collection.name" class="w-75 align-self-center">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
<img [src]="collection[product.name]" [alt]="collection.name" class="w-75 align-self-center">
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi could you try to write this:

```
   <!-- For the image of productOne -->
    <img [src]="collection?.productOne" [alt]="collection.name" class="w-75 align-self-center">

   <!-- For the image of productTwo-->
    <img [src]="collection?.productTwo" [alt]="collection.name" class="w-75 align-self-center">
```

Do not forget the operator `?.` to be safe if the value is `null`.